# Query to get driver (cab driver) whose rating is increasing week on week

Tags: oracle11g

| tripid | driverid | driver rating | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 7/11/2019 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 7/12/2019 |
| 3 | a | 1 | 7/19/2019 |
| 4 | b | 3 | 7/20/2019 |
| 5 | a | 2 | 7/21/2019 |
| 6 | b | 3 | 7/22/2019 |
| 7 | A | 1 | 7/22/2019 |
| 8 | b | 4 | 7/23/2019 |

Let's say we have a table called driver_rating that contains above data.

Need a query to get driver details (dirver_id and rating) whose average rating is increasing every week (Last 7 Days average we need to get of driver rating).

We need to take average of the last 7 days of driver_rating for each driver and return only one row for the driver whose rating is increasing like below,

Driver ID: b, Trip Date: 23-07-19, Weekly Average: 3.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS with different syntaxes and supporting different functions; which one are you using?

Comment: I'm currently trying in oracle...

Comment: Why weekly average for driver `b` and date `23-07-19` is 3 for last 7 days? I see 3 rows with ratings 3,3,4, and average is 3⅓..

Answer (score 0):

We can use the difference between two `row_numbers` to achieve this :

So basically, the row number assigned by date should correspond to the row number assigned by driver rating. When both match, the difference will be zero across all rows.

```
with cte as (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by driverid order by dt, tripid)
              - row_number() over (partition by driverid order by driver_rating, tripid) as grp
  from mytable t
)
select t.driverid, max(dt) as trip_date, avg(driver_rating) as weekly_avrg
from mytable t
inner join (
  select driverid
  from cte
  group by driverid
  having count(*) = count(case when grp = 0 then 1 end)
) s on s.driverid = t.driverid
group by t.driverid
```

Which for this simple data :

```
create table mytable (
  tripid int,
  driverid  varchar(10), 
  driver_rating int,           
  dt date
);

insert into mytable
select 1 as tripid, 'a' as driverid,  1 as driver_rating, date '2019-07-11' as dt from dual union all
select 2, 'b',  2, date '2019-07-12' from dual union all
select 3, 'a',  1, date '2019-07-19' from dual union all
select 4, 'b',  3, date '2019-07-20' from dual union all
select 5, 'a',  2, date '2019-07-21' from dual union all
select 6, 'b',  3, date '2019-07-22' from dual union all
select 7, 'a',  1, date '2019-07-22' from dual union all
select 8, 'b',  4, date '2019-07-23' from dual
```

Results :

```
DRIVERID    TRIP_DATE   WEEKLY_AVRG
b           23-JUL-19   3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sTUEoR_p)

Comment: We need to take average of the last 7 days of driver_rating for each driver and return only one row for the driver whose rating is increasing like below,     
                                             
drvr_id     trip_date      weekly_avrg   
b         23-07-19         3

Comment: Please edit your simple data accordingly and share the expected output

Comment: drvr_id     trip_date      weekly_avrg_rting   
b         23-07-19             3

Comment: Can you check my recent edit ?